# Comma-separated listbox

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, textblock

I have a Listbox with horizontal orientation and I need the Textblock values to be separated by commas.

I've reached this solution:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="toStringDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock  Margin="2,0,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Run Text="{Binding name}"/>
            <Run Text=","/>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But this outputs trailing commas: `value1,value2,value3,`

I need the last comma to be collapsed if its the last item in the Observable Collection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you really need `ListBox` in this case? You can use single `TextBlock` element and format string from code

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".